# Quantum Monte Carlo for harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, simulations

I'm trying to calculate harmonic oscillator using quantum monte carlo (path integral and metropolis algorithm). It's one particle in harmonic potential. I know the theory. One divides the partition function into multiple factors and then Suzuki-Trotter is used and finally matrix elements in position base are calculated. The full energy of a particle is given by the formula:

$<E>=-\frac{M}{2\beta^2} \sum_{i=1}^M(q_i-q_{i+1})^2+ \frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M V(q_i) + \frac{M}{2\beta} $, where M is the number of partitions of partition function or number of points on path - whatever - I hope you understand what M is. Planck constant is 1 and so is the mass of the particle (m=1).

The problem I have is that the energy calculated this way is dependent on M and it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong. Thanks for help.